# What is the distinction between ALL_PROCEDURES and DBA_PROCEDURES, and other schema tables?

Tags: oracle, information-schema

I recently failed to find a known procedure when searching `ALL_PROCEDURES`, and on a whim tried `DBA_PROCEDURES`: lo, there it is.  The doc pages ([ALL_](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_2025.htm); [DBA_](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/statviews_4174.htm#REFRN23168)) both say "...lists all functions and procedures along with their associated properties."  Oracle seems to have a curious definition of "all".

I'm posting this on DBA rather than SO, though it's a pretty basic question, on the basis that schema management is generally a DBA role rather than a developer role.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [here](https://community.oracle.com/thread/356476?start=0&tstart=0)

```
USER_TABLES describes the relational tables owned by the current user.
ALL_TABLES describes the relational tables accessible to the current user.
DBA_TABLES describes all relational tables in the database.
```

Accessible != all!